# vbox cloned centos7 fix same ip new to have different ip from cloned one

Tags: centos, virtualbox, dhclient

I cloned centos7 vm in virtualbox, but they ended up with same ip address. My network preferences are my created NAT network with: 10.0.2.0/24

Both vms uses this network i created, but they have same ip address: 10.0.2.15. Tried to run `dhclient -r -v` to release and renew, but still got same ip.

Comment: have you tried by selecting option "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards" while creating clone of VM?

Comment: @SunilBhoi I missed that part. Can it be done still even after it is created? Did a lot of changes to it now and would not want to repeat the clone process.

Comment: I cloned another one with re-initialize mac but it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the DHCP is enabled ? In VirtualBox, go to Preferences -> Network, then edit the NAT Network you created. You should have this window :

[VirtualBox edit network window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCrB2.png)

If "Supports DHCP" is checked, you can also set a static IP inside your VMs. Execute the command `ip address` and check your working interface (probably ens160). Edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface-name>` (e.g. ifcfg-ens160) and change according to your network.

You should have something like this (some lines are omitted) :

```
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=192.168.2.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.2.254
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.8.4
DEFROUTE=yes
NAME=ens160
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
```

Then restart the network service with `sudo systemctl restart network`.